# Setences with Grammar Points/ Phrases: 再说，越来越，要不然，被了吧， 没有那么，楼

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

I have a bunch of English sentences I need to translate. For some the sentences, I need to use specific phrases or words. I was wondering if someone could check if they are correct or not. If they are not correct, please tell me what I can fix.

1. He bought some fruit and brought it here for us.

他买了一些水果和为我们带了这里。

2. Let's not go out to run, it's late, moreover it's so cold outside. Use：再说

我们不去外面跑步，因为晚了，再说外面很冷。

3. If you can speak in Chinese more often, your speaking will get better and better. Use：越来越

如果你说更多的中文，你的发言会越来越好。

4. We should eat the fruits, otherwise they will go bad. Use：要不然

我们应该吃水果，要不然它们会变质的。

5. The school computers were stolen, weren't they? Use：。。。被了吧？

学校的电脑被偷了吧？On the instruction sheet, the 被 and 了吧 aren't separated. However, I placed a 偷 in between the two. I was wondering if this is ok or not.

6. Chinese is not as difficult as people think。 Use：没有。。。那么

中文没有人们想那么难。

7. The place I live is to the north of the Student Well Center. Use： Student Center - 学生健康中心

我住的地方在学生健康中心的北边。

8. The language lab is inside the building to the south of the computer center. Use：楼-building

语言实验室在计算机中心南侧的楼里。

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 - 8 are all correct (in question four, translate 'go bad' as '变坏' or '腐坏' is better than '变质'

The first problem in question one is the "and" between two verb phrases indicates the two actions occur one after another, therefore you should treat it the same as 'then'. Use '然后' instead of '和'.

The second problem is "for us" here doesn't mean "for our sake" (为) but "(to) us" "（给）我们”.

The third problem is  the location "here" in "brought it here for us" should still be placed before the object in Chinese

The correct sentence is 他买了一些水果[然后]带到这里[给]我们

Comment: For question 6, do you think 中文没有人们想象的那么难。 is a better sentence? Thanks

Comment: 中文没有人们想象中那么难 would be even better